# How can i make createprocess reindirect input success, I have successully get the reindirect out put result

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I searched a lot on internet, but most of them are talking about reindirect output. No one gives any successful reindirect input example. For my codes below, it gave right output when I ran command "ipconfig" or "192.168.0.10" because child process ends after running these commands, no input needed. But when I ran command "ftp" instead of "ipconfig" child process which is console is waiting for the next input command. And I tried to write 11111 as input to console in this case as you can see. However console did not receive my input command and waiting for the input command forever. How can I successfully response to "ftp" command in this program and keep console running

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain(
                   HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpComLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr; 
    HANDLE hRead,hWrite;

char command[256];
char testBuf[256] = {0};
    strcpy(command, "ipconfig");
//  strcpy(command, "ping 192.168.0.10")    
//  strcpy(command, "ftp");

secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

HANDLE hTxtFile = CreateFile("tmp.txt", GENERIC_ALL, 0, &secAttr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hTxtFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error createfile", NULL, MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile("Write.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &secAttr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hWriteFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error createWritefile", NULL, MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; 
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
GetStartupInfo(&startupInfo); 
startupInfo.hStdError = hTxtFile;    
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hTxtFile;
startupInfo.hStdInput = hWriteFile;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW; 
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

char output[10240] = {0};
DWORD bytesRead;

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, command,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo)) 
{ 
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error createprocess", NULL, MB_OK);
    CloseHandle(hWrite); 
    CloseHandle(hRead); 
    return FALSE; 
} 

DWORD processExitCode = 0;
strcpy(testBuf, "11111\r\n");
while (GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess, &processExitCode))
{
    WriteFile(hWriteFile, testBuf, 7, &bytesRead, NULL);
    if (processExitCode != STILL_ACTIVE) 
    {
        //  MessageBox(NULL, "End process", NULL, MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}

SetFilePointer(hTxtFile, NULL, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
ReadFile(hTxtFile, output, 10240, &bytesRead, NULL);
CloseHandle(hTxtFile);

MessageBox(NULL, output, NULL, MB_OK);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) need close handles, which you not do 2) `hStdInput` must have `FILE_GENERIC_READ` access 3) most programs when view empty input ( `NumberOfBytesRead == 0` or *ZwReadFile* return *STATUS_END_OF_FILE* ) simply exit - so your code will be not worked with filesystem files. or you need write data to `hStdInput` *before* you create process.

Comment: 4) general note - use synchronous shared file as you use it - incorrect - file share *CurrentByteOffset*. when you call *WriteFile* you can write not from position which you think, because child process can change position (this can avoid by use direct offset in *OVERLAPPED*). also your write change *CurrentByteOffset* in shared file object and affect child process 5) use `processExitCode != STILL_ACTIVE` not 100% reliable way - what if child call `ExitProcess(STILL_ACTIVE)` ?

Comment: I already found the problem in my project, so basically when we use    STARTF_USESTDHANDLES property.    createprocess will create non interactive console which means it can only run one command line in a    createprocess call. Any idea I can use createprocess to create a interactive redirecting console which takes user input according to the last console output? Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no such thing as a "noninteractive console" and since you are redirecting the input the console isn't involved anyway.  The problem is that you are trying to use a file as if it were a pipe, which doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398214/redirect-ftp-pipe-in-c Here, I changed my codes and it works perfectly now, but I encounter the same problem as this OP. When we input "ftp" or "wmic" in a real console we receive "ftp> " and when we input a invalid command like "123" we receive "Invalid command". But this interactive operation between parent process and child console process does not happen in my codes or all the redirecting programs I have found on the internet. So haven't really seen a VC console works exactly like real cmd.exe console

Comment: You are choosing to redirect input and output, and the child process is responding to that choice by being less verbose.  This is all working as designed.  I don't know what you mean by "VC console" (a Google search just turns up stuff about Nintendo) but you don't need `cmd.exe` in order to have a console, if you want the child process to use the console just don't specify the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect ftp pipe in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398214/redirect-ftp-pipe-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting (not "reindirecting") input works just the same as redirecting output. Of course, the flow of data is in the opposite direction. This means that the process **reads** from the file. This in turn means when you open a handle for writing, as you do in the example code:

```
HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile("Write.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, ...);
```

the process will not be able to **read** from it. You must open the file for reading:

```
HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile("Write.txt", GENERIC_READ, ...);
```

But then, this also means that you must prepare the input that you want to send down to the process **in advance**. It does not help to write to the file *after* you have created the process.

If you do not know the data that you have to send to the process in advance, you cannot use a file for standard input, but you must use something else, such as a (named or anonymous) pipe.

Answer (score 0):

you must redirect the console output and then write the buffer into file

1)

```
    /* Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT */
    if(!CreatePipe(&hChildStdoutRd, &hChildStdoutWr, &saAttr, 0))
        BAIL_OUT(-1);
```

2)

```
    /* Duplicate the pipe HANDLE */
    if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hChildStdoutRd, GetCurrentProcess(), &hChildStdoutRdDup, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
        BAIL_OUT(-1);
```

3)

```
CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead;
    DWORD dwAvail = 0;
    if (!PeekNamedPipe(hChildStdoutRdDup, NULL, 0, NULL, &dwAvail, NULL) || !dwAvail)
        return;
    if (!ReadFile(hChildStdoutRdDup, chBuf, min(BUFSIZE - 1, dwAvail), &dwRead, NULL) || !dwRead)
        return;
    chBuf[dwRead] = 0;
```

Please find more details here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5531/Redirecting-an-arbitrary-Console-s-Input-Output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398214/redirect-ftp-pipe-in-c Here, I changed my codes and it works perfectly now, but I encounter the same problem as this OP. When we input "ftp" or "wmic" in a real console we receive "ftp> " and when we input a invalid command like "123" we receive "Invalid command". But this interactive operation between parent process and child console process does not happen in my codes or all the redirecting programs I he found on the internet.  I had download the this demo and it has the same problem when I ran it